# Centroid of Triangulated Surface in 3D

Tags: triangulation, centroid

Think about the irregular 3D shape's surface (i.e stone) is triangulated.

I have:

- Vertices. `x,y,z` coordinate of each point (pointCloud).
- Faces. Contains info about, each triangle's vertex.
- Area of each triangle
- Volume of whole shape

With the given information, how to find exact coordinate of that whole triangulated surface's centroid?

Comment: My guess is get the centroid of every triangle and then average would work but have to give it more thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the **centroid of the surface** by accumulating the centroids of each triangle weighted by each triangle mass, then in the end divide by the total mass. In algorithm, this gives:

```
mg : vector3d <- (0,0,0)
m : real <- 0
For each triangle t 
   m <- m + area(t)
   mg <- mg + area(t) * centroid(t)
End for
Surfacecentroid <- mg / m
```

where:

```
centroid(t) = 1/3 (p1+p2+p3)
area(t) = 1/2 * || cross(p2-p1, p3-p1) ||
```

Now if what you want is the **centroid of the volume enclosed by the surface**, the algorithm is different, you need to decompose the volume into tetrahedra and accumulate tetrahedra centroids as follows:

```
mg : vector3d <- (0,0,0)
m : real <- 0
For each triangle t = (p1,p2,p3)
   m <- m + signed_volume(O,p1,p2,p3)
   mg <- mg + signed_volume(O,p1,p2,p3) * centroid(O,p1,p2,p3)
End for
volumeCentroid <- (1/m) * mg
```

where

```
   O=(0,0,0) and
   centroid(p1,p2,p3,p4) = 1/4 (p1+p2+p3+p4) 
   signed_volume(p1,p2,p3,p4) = 1/6 * dot(p2-p1, cross(p3-p1, p4-p1))
```

The formula works even when O is outside the surface because the signed volumes of the tetrahedra parts outside the surface exactly cancel-out (if you love math, another way of thinking about the algorithm is applying Stokes formula to the volume computation).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Weighted one works fine.
For the volume:
-What is `p4` ? is that `O` or Which one is `O`?
-Is `O = (0,0,0)` always constant ?
--If Yes, Why subtract other points from `O` if it is zero?
-What is `centroid` function here?

Comment: (p1,p2,p3,p4) denote the four vertices of a tetrahedron. The formula accumulates the signed volumes and their centroid (centroid of a tetrahedron = 1/4(p1 + p2 + p3 +p4). For O you can take an arbitrary point, so clearly it is good to take O=(0,0,0) (makes computations simpler).